# Uncaught fx error in js

Tags: javascript, plugins

I am having the problem with woocommerce-currency-converter-widget plugins i have

> "got Uncaught fx error"

. when i was trying to change currency in developer console. Please guide me how to solve this error. Currency widget is top left side above home page slider.

> My Website URL: vandvshop.com/production/

I am in trouble please help me.

Comment: Please add more information to question.

Comment: In my website when i am trying to change currency, yeah currency symbol changed but product price becomes 0 not converted to chosen currency type. when you look at product price on first time page load in INR then click on USD currency and again check price of LATEST PRODUCTS section products it's showing Zero and throw js error in console. My Website URL :- http://vandvshop.com/production/

Comment: Hi, Fizer Khan, Please choose currency and then see the error which occurs in console not in page load FB is different error.

Comment: @BadruddinKachwala look my /answer/ below are you experiencing the same behaviour?

Comment: @badruddinKachwala what are your thoughts on the Code throwing the error? what did you modify in the configs?

Answer (score 0):

Not a fully answer yet, but an approach on solving.

```
UPDATE:
Analyzed [X]
Found Code throwing error [X]
Feedback from OP []
Resolved[]
```

Console output before pressing any currency.

```
woocommerce_current_currency=; PHPSESSID=bbd72ed061219517d131970655c5f259; _ga=GA1.2.1963075693.1408956497
```

Steps I did after:

1st Clicked Euro Icon

Console Output:

```
woocommerce_current_currency=; PHPSESSID=bbd72ed061219517d131970655c5f259; _ga=GA1.2.1963075693.1408956497
```

Nothing changed

2nd Clicked on [image]

Console Output:

```
woocommerce_current_currency=EUR; PHPSESSID=bbd72ed061219517d131970655c5f259; _ga=GA1.2.1963075693.1408956497
```

Ok nice, now you can see that current_currency changed to EUR

3rd Clicked on Dollar

Console Output:

```
Uncaught fx error money.min.js?ver=0.1.3:2
b.convert money.min.js?ver=0.1.3:2
c.to money.min.js?ver=0.1.3:2
(anonymous function) conversion.min.js?ver=1.2.3:1
n.extend.each jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:2
n.fn.n.each jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:2
u conversion.min.js?ver=1.2.3:1
(anonymous function) conversion.min.js?ver=1.2.3:1
n.event.dispatch jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:3
r.handle
```

Conclusion: Somehow it has problems with switching currency

EDIT: Below is the Code throwing the error, may it helps.

```
// Returns the exchange rate to `target` currency from `base` currency
    var getRate = function(to, from) {
        // Save bytes in minified version
        var rates = fx.rates;

        // Make sure the base rate is in the rates object:
        rates[fx.base] = 1;


    //////////// This is the part throwing the error!  ////////////
 //////////// Throw an error if either rate isn't in the rates array //////////// 



if ( !rates[to] || !rates[from] ) throw "fx error"; 


     //////////// //////////// //////////// //////////// //////////// ////////////


        // If `from` currency === fx.base, return the basic exchange rate for the `to` currency
        if ( from === fx.base ) {
            return rates[to];
        }

        // If `to` currency === fx.base, return the basic inverse rate of the `from` currency
        if ( to === fx.base ) {
            return 1 / rates[from];
        }

        // Otherwise, return the `to` rate multipled by the inverse of the `from` rate to get the
        // relative exchange rate between the two currencies
        return rates[to] * (1 / rates[from]);
    };
```

Comment: But what is the code should i write for correct one.

Comment: please answer my Questions in the comments